# Convert TIF to another TIF with Jpeg compression

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a Tif file from LWZ compression to Jpeg compression. The code is below

```
        // There is only one row in the Datatable
        foreach (DataRow ImageRow in dtImage.Rows)
        {
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            memoryStream.Write((Byte[])ImageRow[0], 0, ((Byte[])ImageRow[0]).Length);
            Image MyImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
            MyImage.Save(@"c:\_temp\abc1.tif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            memoryStream.Flush();
        }
```

abc1.tif is created successfully. But when I look at the properties of the file, the compression is empty. How do I know that the file has is compressed correctly?

[image]

Comment: Open it with a drawing application like Paint or Paint.NET

Comment: How do I tell the compression after opening in Paint?

Comment: If you open the file in [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) and press "i", you will find a section "Compression". It's easier than using a hex editor to examine the file content.

Comment: TIFF is an acronym for Thousands of Incompatible File Formats.  You can't get all of them, for compression using LZW [look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.compression(v=vs.110).aspx).